# Trying to create three classes and draw crayon box. How to draw crayons in constructor?

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, paint, jcomponent

The instructions is to create a Crayon objects that have height, location, and color. The object should also draw the crayon. The program should have and hold 8 different crayons of different colors. The crayons are to be help in an `ArrayList`. We are required three classes: `Crayon`, `CrayonBoxComponent`, and `CrayonBoxViewer`. My classes simply aren't working and I'm not sure how to connect the three classes. On top of this I do not know how to draw the crayon within the Crayon object. Also, the crayons are supposed to drawn using a `loop`, which I also do not know how to do. Thank you!

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Crayon extends JComponent
{
    int loc;
    int h;
    Color myColor;
    private JPanel panel;

    public Crayon(int location, int height, Color input)
    {
        loc=location;
        h=height;
        myColor=input;

    }

    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setColor(myColor);
        g.fillRect(loc, 40, 40, h);



    }


}
```

...

```
  import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
class CrayonBoxComponent extends JComponent
{

  public void paint(Graphics g)
  {
    //typecast
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    ArrayList<Crayon> box = new ArrayList<Crayon>();

     Crayon c1=new Crayon(10, 200, Color.RED);
        box.add(c1);
     Crayon c2=new Crayon(60, 200, Color.BLUE);
        box.add(c2);
     Crayon c3=new Crayon(110, 200, Color.CYAN);
        box.add(c3);
     Crayon c4=new Crayon(160, 200, Color.GREEN);
        box.add(c4);
     Crayon c5=new Crayon(210, 200, Color.MAGENTA);
        box.add(c5);
     Crayon c6=new Crayon(260, 200, Color.ORANGE);
        box.add(c6);
     Crayon c7=new Crayon(310, 200, Color.BLACK);
        box.add(c7);
     Crayon c8=new Crayon(360, 200, Color.YELLOW);
        box.add(c8);



    }


}
```

....

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class CrayonBoxViewer
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setSize(1000, 1000);
        frame.setTitle("Crayon Box");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        CrayonBoxComponent component = new CrayonBoxComponent();
        frame.add(component);

        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I kept your `Crayon` class and your `CrayonBoxView` class. Inside the `CrayonBoxComponent` class, I did this

```js
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.util.ArrayList;

class CrayonBoxComponent extends JComponent
{
  public ArrayList<Crayon> addCrayons()
  {
   ArrayList<Crayon> box = new ArrayList<Crayon>();
   
   Crayon c1=new Crayon(10, 200, Color.RED);
      box.add(c1);
      Crayon c2=new Crayon(60, 200, Color.BLUE);
      box.add(c2);
      Crayon c3=new Crayon(110, 200, Color.CYAN);
      box.add(c3);
      Crayon c4=new Crayon(160, 200, Color.GREEN);
      box.add(c4);
      Crayon c5=new Crayon(210, 200, Color.MAGENTA);
      box.add(c5);
      Crayon c6=new Crayon(260, 200, Color.ORANGE);
      box.add(c6);
      Crayon c7=new Crayon(310, 200, Color.BLACK);
      box.add(c7);
      Crayon c8=new Crayon(360, 200, Color.YELLOW);
      box.add(c8);
      
      return box;
  }

  public void print(Graphics g)
  {
   Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
   for (int i = 0; i < addCrayons().size(); i++){
    addCrayons().get(i).paint(g2);
   }
  }
 
}
```

EDIT: You should also probably change the height and width of crayon rectangles to make them look more like crayons

EDIT2: I accidentally wrongly named a method that I called. I renamed my previous `paint` method to `print` and fixed the error within that method.